# Ruby / Rails working with Delphi back end

Tags: ruby, delphi, firebird

Can anyone point me to some sources or tutorials that would help me wrap my head around using Rails to connect/inquire with a Delphi backend (using a Firebird database).

Also, a few questions regarding this setup.
Is a Delphi back-end faster than a rails back end? Delphi seems to have far better support for connecting to firebird than the ruby drivers would.

What is the current best choice method for making requests? The REST stuff, or some kind of RPC? or something else?

Since we are currently a Delphi shop, i assumed the back end being in delphi would help us leverage current skills better.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:  Little bit about the set up.

So to make this easier to explain lets just say its essentially a todo organizer.  So the frontend would be a calendar showing what is due on each day.  Or perhaps list views of that information, etc.  The "back-end" as I had called it would be something that is storing to a Firebird database.  the RoR calendar site would then request information about Todos, or todos on a given day or date range, perhaps information about certain contacts.  All of which is stored in Firebird.

I do realize you can do the front-end part in delphi as well but I'm trying to phase out Delphi in favor of newer languages.

Comment: If you have the most feeling with Delphi, why not consider a Delphi front-end as well. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793112/what-web-application-framework-for-delphi-is-recommended

Comment: Maybe you can describe your architecture more detailed - what is a 'backend', is it business logic, which uses Firebird as data storage? Do you want to use RoR only for the presentation layer? I see no problem using REST (using a HTTP server implementation for Delphi) to connect from RoR to the Delphi backend. However REST is request/response, maybe you also need some asynchronous communication between frontend and backend.

Comment: Thanks I updated it a bit.

Comment: The newer, the better? Are you sure? Most languages have a purpose, and it will be better to use the language and framework matching your target and maximizing your ROI. But the more languages you know, the better, IMHO.

Comment: Not better because its new, but in a web/mobile world there are many other languages that are better suited.

Comment: @TheTyBish This was my point. ;)

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK you need much more than a RESTful API to run a RoR application.

Most of the work is done on the server side: MVC model, data persistence, routing, etc...

Using Delphi as back end will need a huge amount of work.

Take a look at some projects, if you need a RESTful server built in Delphi:

- Delphi on rails https://code.google.com/p/delphionrails
- Delphi Web Script https://code.google.com/p/dwscript
- Delphi Relax http://code.marcocantu.com/p/delphirelax
- DataSnap (directly in Delphi)
- our mORMot framework http://mormot.net

All implement direct connection to Firebird, and DoR + mORMot + DWS sounds to have better performance.

A Delphi based server will in all cases be more responsive.

DoR is more close to RoR - as the name states! Delphi Relax seems also close to it (even if I wonder if Marco will still maintain it - 5 months without commit).
DataSnap is more RAD, and integrated within the IDE.
DWS has a new DB backend, and the same high performance HTTP server than mORMot.
mORMot has a full client-server ORM, but web clients are to be build in AJAX - SmartMobileStudio is preferred.